# How to get a merge log for a branch?

Tags: git, version-control

`git log` lists all commits, from all branches that have been merged into HEAD. I want to get a list of merges, so I can see which branches have been merged into this one, and when.

How can I get that information? I'm looking for something besides "launch gitk and look at the graph", since I know that one, but for very large histories with many branches this doesn't scale very well. A text result to a text query is probably ideal.

Comment: @Andrew, if you can have git1.6.4, you could consider Jakub's answer as the official one. He does know his git.

Comment: Agreed.  That's generous of you to offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With modern git (if you have version 1.6.4 or newer you have this) you can use simply

```
$ git log --merges
```

If you want to see only merges into current branch, you can add `--first-parent` option:

```
$ git log --merges --first-parent
```

Comment: Excellent! I should read those release notes more carefully ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg63351.html), playing a bit with [git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
$ git log --no-walk $(git rev-list --parents HEAD | sed -n "s/ .* .*//p")
```

would give you the list of merges since the last tag in a repository.
Not fully tested myself though.

Comment: It seems to go well past the last tag, but this is exactly what I want.  The complexity of the command is a testament to the flexibility of git, but also it's *complexity*. :|

Comment: Or you can use `git log --merges` with git version 1.6.4 or newer.